# Call javascript function(which is there in visualforce) on click of custom button

Tags: visualforce, javascript, button

I have a javascript function in a VF page, can I call this javascript function through custom button(created at object level).
I don't want to rewrite this javascript at button level, I just want to call this JS function onclick of custom button(creating at object level)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you be more specific about where the "object level" button is, what the "button level" means, etc?

Comment: I am creating a cutom button in Contact object